# I need to create a simple pie chart in SAS from a Proc SQL Table

Tags: sql, sas

I need to create a pie chart showing gender distribution for a state pulled through a macro variable. The code for the sql table looks like this:

```
proc sql;
create table pie_data as
select distinct mean(Men2017/(Men2017 + Women2017)) format=comma10.2 as Men2017, mean(Women2017/(Men2017 + Women2017)) format=comma10.2 as Women2017
from project.county_data
where State= &StateValue;
quit;
```

The output of the table looks like this:

Men2017     Women2017

0.49        0.51

I don't know how to do it through proc gchart since Men2017 and Women2017 are technically separate variables, and I can't manually input the data since it needs to be dynamic. Any suggestions to how I should approach this? I'm new to SAS.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but maybe leads to a solution. If you have access to Enterprise Guide or SAS Studio, there are point-click options to build a Proc GChart. Then you can get at the underlying SAS code. Then with a little help from Google or this site you can alter the code to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Use PROC TRANSPOSE to transpose the data

Rough idea, may need to re-name variables:

```
data pie_data;
input Men2017 Women2017;
cards;
0.49 0.51
;;;;

proc transpose data=pie_data out=pie_data_long;
var MEN2017 WOMEN2017;
run;

proc sgpie data=pie_data_long;
pie col1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PROC TRANSPOSE` can re-arrange your data so that the values appear in 1 variable. Then you can easily do the pie chart. Add the following after your `PROC SQL` step.

```
proc transpose data= pie_data out=pie_transpose name=gender;
    var men2017 women2017;
run;

title 'Men and women, 2017';
proc gchart data=pie_transpose;
    pie gender / sumvar=col1 noheading;
run;
title;
```